# sentinel list always gives the same output when reading it, why? C

Tags: c

sentinel list always gives the same output when reading it, why?
Please be patient, im new to this and i have no idea what went wrong.

here is the code i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*----------------------------------------------------------Strukturak------------------*/
typedef struct tempfile
{
    int ev;
    int hnap;
    int nap;
    int ora;
    int perc;
    int meret;
    char nev[218];
    char kiterjesztes[218];
}tempfile;
typedef struct tmplist
{
    tempfile fadat;
    struct tmplist *kov;
} templist;
/*----------------------------------------------------------Strukturak------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------Listamuveletek--------------*/


templist* wardedtemplist(void)
{
    templist *ward1;
    templist *ward2;
    ward1 = (templist*)malloc(1 * sizeof(templist));
    ward2 = (templist*)malloc(1 * sizeof(templist));
    ward1->kov = ward2;
    ward2->kov = NULL;
    return ward1;
}
templist* ujtemplistelem(tempfile adat)
{
    templist *ujtemplistelem;
    ujtemplistelem = (templist*)malloc(1 * sizeof(templist));
    if (ujtemplistelem != NULL)
    {
        ujtemplistelem->fadat = adat;
        ujtemplistelem->kov = NULL;
    }
    return ujtemplistelem;
}
templist* beszurastemplist(templist* ujtemplistelem, templist* ward1)
{

    templist* wifi;
    wifi = (templist*)malloc(1 * sizeof(templist));
    wifi->kov = ward1->kov;
    ward1->kov = ujtemplistelem;
    ujtemplistelem->kov = wifi->kov;
    free(wifi);

    return ward1;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------Listamuveletek--------------*/
/*---------------------------------dir txt file beolvasasa (huh boi ez nehez volt)------*/

int main(void)
{
    char input[1024];
    char edited[1024];
    int i = 0;
    int p = 0;
    FILE *temp;
    tempfile a;
    templist* ujlea;
    templist* dirlist;
    templist*aktualiselem;
    dirlist = wardedtemplist();

    system("dir>temp.txt");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    if (temp == NULL)
        return -1;

    while (fgets(input, sizeof input, temp))
    {
        if (input[0] == ' ' || input[0] == '\n')
        {
            continue;//atugorja azokat a sorokat amik space vagy ujsorral kezdodnek
        }
        if (strstr(input, "<DIR>"))
        {
            continue;//atugorja azokat a sorokat okat amikben benne van a <DIR>
        }
        while (input[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (input[i] != '˙')
            {
                edited[p] = input[i];
                p++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        edited[p] = '\0';                        //rongyá editelése a sornak
        p = 0;
        i = 0;
        while (edited[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (edited[i] == '.')
                edited[i] = ' ';
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;


        sscanf(edited, "%d  %d  %d   %d:%d    %d %s %s\n", &a.ev, &a.hnap, &a.nap, &a.ora, &a.perc, &a.meret, &a.nev, &a.kiterjesztes);
        printf("%d.%d.%d. %d:%d  niz  %d byte   %s.%s\n", a.ev, a.hnap, a.nap, a.ora, a.perc, a.meret, a.nev, a.kiterjesztes);
        ujlea = ujtemplistelem(a);
        dirlist = beszurastemplist(ujlea, dirlist);
    }

    fclose(temp);
    system("DEL temp.txt");




    aktualiselem = dirlist->kov; //Első kihagy
    while (aktualiselem->kov != NULL) // Ucso kihagy
    {
        printf("%d.%d.%d. %d:%d    %d byte   %s.%s\n", a.ev, a.hnap, a.nap, a.ora, a.perc, a.meret, a.nev, a.kiterjesztes);
        printf("==========\n\n");
        aktualiselem = aktualiselem->kov;
    }



    printf("press enter\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


/*---------------------------------dir txt file beolvasasa (huh boi ez nehez volt)------*/
```

The first printf prints the data that will goes into the list, the second printf prints the sentinel lists data.

The first one goes well, do what its need to do,
but the second is printing only one element as many times as many data goes in.

What causes this?

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: You seem to always allocate 2 nodes, but then leak the second one by overwriting `kov` on the first one.

Comment: Ah I got it! in the second printf i just simply printed the last tempfile a; over and over again.
I knew it will be a small rookie mistake :D

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  3) the parameter contains `1 *`  which has absolutely not effect.

Comment: when calling any of the scanf() family of functions (in this case: sscanf()), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. NOTE: using a single space is sufficient for any amount (including none) of white space separating the data in the input.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please honor the right margin (usually column 72 or 80) Usually placing a newline after the comma delimiters will accomplish this goal.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to name a function the same as a local variable.  Function names should be 'active tense'  rather than just the name of some object.

Comment: the call to `ujtemplistelem()` can return NULL, so the caller should be checking the returned value for NULL  and if NULL, then do not use it

Comment: the calls to `system()` with commands of `DIR` or `DEL` might work on Windows, but will not work on linux, etc.  (However, for linux, lower case `dir` and `del` will work.  I.E. the posted code is not portable

Comment: the function: `beszurastemplist()` is doing an awful lot of work to simply copy two fields,  So why all the messing with `malloc()`, etc?

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1024.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(edited, "%d  %d  %d   %d:%d    %d %s %s\n",
            &a.ev,
            &a.hnap,
            &a.nap,
            &a.ora,
            &a.perc,
            &a.meret,
            &a.nev,
            &a.kiterjesztes);` the format string should be: `"%d%d%d%d:%d%d %s %s"`  because do not want to try to consume trailing white space AND array names degrade to the address of the first byte of the array, so no need to have a leading `&`

Comment: regarding: if (input[i] != '˙') the compiler sees this as a multicharacter char constant. And, due to limited range of data type, this if() statement is always true.

Comment: Wow man, thank you so much! these tips and corrections were so helpful!
Thanks for your time